# How to set the initial weights to Xavier?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I would like to set the initial weights in Pytorch to Xavier.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        # self.linear1 = nn.Linear(1, 516*4*4)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 512*8)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(256*16, 256*8)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(256*8, 1)

    def forward(self, x):       
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)        
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)        
        x = self.linear3(x)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each layer using the [`children`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=children#torch.nn.Module.children) generator and initialize the layer weights using the built-in [`xavier_uniform_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html?highlight=xavier_uniform_#torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_) initializer provided by [`nn.init`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch-nn-init) module.

For example, you could put this in your `__init__` definition:

```
for m in self.children():
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)
```